# Is it possible to run an asset from an image?

Tags: python, kubernetes, machine-learning, pipeline, dagster

I am trying to understand what I can really do with Dagster.

I have some Python codes already containerised and pushed to a container registry.
I was wondering if in a Dagster'op or asset I can read those images and run the final pipeline on my Kubernetes cluster.

For example, I may have an image that performs some multiplication and it's on GCR. Does Dagster offer any tool for pulling this image and then allowing me to do something like:

```
@asset(PULL_IMAGE)
def my_asset():
    from MY_IMAGE_CODE import function_1, function_2
    function_1()
```

Then, I would like to use Dagster-kubernetes to run this pipeline on Kubernetes.

I tried to get an idea from Dagster docs but I couldn't find anything.
I had a look at various GitHub Repos but many of them are using an old version of Dagster.
I jumped into https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/libraries/dagster-k8s and https://dagster.io/integrations/dagster-docker but I am not really understanding how to link them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact use case, [Dagster Pipes](https://docs.dagster.io/guides/dagster-pipes) and [`dagster-k8s`](https://docs.dagster.io/guides/dagster-pipes/kubernetes) may solve your problem. According to them, it is

> a protocol for integrating and launching compute into remote execution environments from Dagster and a toolkit for building those integrations.

In your example, it would look like this:

```
@asset
def assets_def(
    context: AssetExecutionContext,
    pipes_k8s_client: PipesK8sClient,
) -> MaterializeResult:
    return pipes_k8s_client.run(
        image="some_image", context=context
    ).get_materialize_result()
```